# jQuery animate SVG element

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, jquery-svg

I got a svg in my application. Like

```
<svg id="gt" height="450" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<image id="1_dice" x="0" y="420" height="30" width="30" xlink:href="images/1_coin.png" />
</svg>
```

I got a svg element named '1_dice'. In a HTML button click I would likes to animate the element according to the parameters. Like

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
     $('#1_dice').animate({'x':200},2000);
});
```

I tried this but this doesn't working ...

Comment: If the DOCTYPE of the page is not HTML5 note that IDs must begin with a letter.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. My DOCTYPE is <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

I also changes the name to "dice" . But not working .. even $('#dice').hide(); this is working.. 
plz help

Comment: $('#dice').hide(); -- this is working ... but animate is not working

Comment: oh sorry .. I m not Iranian ... m Indian

Comment: no worries, cool, we have Ramesh in Persia too, beautiful name `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery animate is for animating HTML elements.
For SVG you have to try [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin.
Please follow the link - http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Comment: To be more precise, jQuery animate is for animating CSS properties. Some CSS can apply to SVG elements, such as opacity, fill, stroke. See [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/) for some explanation.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible without a plugin, but it involves a trick then. The issue is that `x` is not a css property but an attribute, and [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) only animates css properties. But you can use the `step` parameter to specify your own custom behavior for the animation.

`foo` is a non-existing *property*, whose animating value we can use in the step function.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    const $image = $('#dice_1');
    $image.animate(
        { 'foo': 200 },
        {
          step: (foo) => $image.attr('x', foo),
          duration: 2000
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This only works if the value you want to give is a number, cause the step function only takes a number.

Comment: Ehhh, this will do... thankfully css has the `rgb()` css function, so I can create a changing svg fill this way...