# How do I toggle an animation for a svg using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

I want this svg drawing to go up when it's clicked and then go down when it's clicked again, and also go up and down a little when it's hovered. I managed to do the hover part and to make it go up once it's clicked, but I cant make it go down when it's clicked again. I figured using "toggle" instead of "click" would work:

```
$('#globoamarillo1').click(function() {
$("#globoamarillo1").animate({top: '-=200px'}, 1000);
```

(changed to)

```
$('#globoamarillo1').toggle(function() {
$("#globoamarillo1").animate({top: '-=200px'}, 1000);
```

But when I use that the drawing goes crazy and flies out of the picture instantly.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqvLyctj/3/

So how can I make it go down when it's clicked again?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789665/jquery-animate-svg-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't seem to do anything when I look at it but here is a thought:

```
<script>
var myToggle = 0;

$('#globoamarillo1').click(function() {
myToggle = (myToggle + 1) % 2;
if( myToggle > 0 ){ $("#globoamarillo1").animate({top: '-=200px'}, 1000); }
   else { $("#globoamarillo1").animate({top: '+=200px'}, 1000); }
}
</script>
```

Everything time you click on it the variable myToggle will toggle between zero(0) and one(1).  Easy peazy. :-)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!